# Inherent issues in a resume template

Tags: document-classes, cv

I modified the resume template found [here](https://github.com/reidmv/resume/blob/master/resume.tex). I am facing the following issues:

1. The bullet points are in the middle of the two lines, I am unable to
   place them directly before the beginning of a sentence.
2. Under the Research Experience, the lines do not seem to occur one
   below the other.

Kindly help.

```
% resume.tex
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,%
    citecolor=black,%
    filecolor=black,%
    linkcolor=black,%
    urlcolor=blue
    %urlcolor=mygreylink     % can put red here to better visualize the links
}
\urlstyle{same}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{.85}
\definecolor{mygreylink}{gray}{.40}
\textheight=9.0in
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.375in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{0.375in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{0.5in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.375in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{0.75in}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{{\large \colorbox{mygrey}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}{\textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}\end{minipage}}}}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
\begin{tabular*}{6.5in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}

\newcommand{\ressubsubheading}[2]{
\begin{tabular*}{6.5in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textit{#1} & \textit{#2} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------

%-----------------------------------------------------------
%General Resume Tips
%   No periods!  Technically, nothing in this document is a full sentence.
%   Use parallelism by ending key words with the same thing,  i.e. "Coordinated; Designed; Communicated".
%   More tips on bottom of this LaTeX document.
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mywebheader}{
\begin{tabular*}{7in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    \textbf{{\LARGE DOMARPS}} & \href{mailto:d92@gmail.com}{ste1@gmail.com}\\
    {\href{https}{Portfolio Website}} &  {(+1)1234531432} \\
    \end{tabular*}
\\
\vspace{0.1in}}

% CHANGE HEADER SOURCE HERE
\mywebheader

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Education}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item
            \ressubheading{{UBC}}{expected May 2017 }{{MS in Computer Science}}{}
                { \footnotesize
                \begin{itemize}
                    %\resitem{\textbf{Available for internship: July 23, 2009; Graduation follows internship}}
                    \resitem{Coursework : Machine Learning, Artificial Intelligence}
                    \resitem{\textbf{Graduate Teaching Assistant}}
                \end{itemize}
                }
        \item
            \ressubheading{PERVSIT}{August 2014}{{Bachelor of Engineering(Hons.) in Electrical and Electronics};\href{https}{GPA:9.64/10.0}}{}
                { \footnotesize
                \begin{itemize}
                \resitem {Coursework : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vitae ultrices. }
                \resitem {Recipient of the {\bf Best Graduating Student Award} \hfill \href{https}{[Certificate]}}
                \end{itemize}
                }

    \end{itemize} % End Education list

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Industrial Experience}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 
            \ressubheading{{Intel}}{Bangalore,India}
                {Logic Design Engineer}{Dec. 2014 -- July 2015}
                { \footnotesize
                \begin{itemize}
                    \resitem{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vitae ultrices. }
                    \resitem{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vitae ultrices. }
                \end{itemize}
                }
        \item 
            \ressubheading{{Nvidia}}{Bangalore}{Designer}{June 2014 -- Dec. 2014}
                { \footnotesize
                \begin{itemize}
                    \resitem{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vitae ultrices. }
                    \resitem{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vitae ultrices. }
                \end{itemize}
                }
            \ressubsubheading{Undergraduate Intern,Memory Architecture Team}{Jan. 2014 -- June. 2014}
                { \footnotesize
                \begin{itemize}
                    \resitem{Added new features to the performance simulator and validation of the model.}
                    \resitem{Added testslists to verify/validate the model for automation of the various steps involved in validation/verification.}
                    \resitem{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vitae ultrices. }
                \end{itemize}
                }
\end{itemize}  % End Experience list

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Research Experience}
\begin{itemize}
        \item 
            \ressubheading{Parallel Tools for High Speed Machines Circuits} \\
{\href{http://dummypage}{Computer Lab, University of Ottawa.}} \hfill{\textbf{{Summer,2013}}}
          { \footnotesize
          \begin{itemize}
           \resitem{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vitae ultrices. }
           \resitem{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vitae ultrices. }%\hfill [Code] [Results]
          \end{itemize}
          }
\end{itemize}
\resheading{\href{dummy}{Projects}}

\begin{description}
\item[Pydom:] { \footnotesize Pydom scans through a list of web pages, grabs the HTML source, and parses interactive elements. These interactive elements written to an XML catalog which is used as the main input for a Selenium .Net project.}

\item[Xerrscrape:] { \footnotesize Used to fill a missing area of product testing, this Python program scans through all XML error logs on the specified server, tallies errors collectively, and sends notifications when an error occurs more than the threshold.}

\item[.Net CWS Test API:] { \footnotesize This framework provides automated testing for RightNow Connect Web Services for SOAP (.Net Toolkit).  Using reflection, objects and NUnit tests are instantiated based on JSON input.}
\item[\href{https://bitbucket.org/dhildreth/canon\_webview}{Canon Webcam API}:] {\footnotesize Allows programmatic authentication and control for Canon 360$^\circ$ Webcams in Python.}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1, modify the `\ressubheading` command as follows:

```
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{6.5in}
                \textbf{#1} \hfill #2 \\
                \textit{#3} \hfill \textit{#4} 
        \end{minipage}\vspace{-6pt}}
```

For #2, enter the four arguments correctly as this:

```
\ressubheading{Parallel Tools for High Speed Machines Circuits}
                    {~}
                    {\href{http://dummypage}{Computer Lab, University of Ottawa.}} 
                    {\textbf{{Summer,2013}}}
```

Now, the complete code:

% resume.tex
        \documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

```
    %-----------------------------------------------------------
    \usepackage{latexsym}
    \usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
    \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks,%
        citecolor=black,%
        filecolor=black,%
        linkcolor=black,%
        urlcolor=blue
        %urlcolor=mygreylink     % can put red here to better visualize the links
    }
    \urlstyle{same}
    \definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{.85}
    \definecolor{mygreylink}{gray}{.40}
    \textheight=9.0in
    \raggedbottom
    \raggedright
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

    % Adjust margins
    \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.375in}
    \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{0.375in}
    \addtolength{\textwidth}{0.5in}
    \addtolength{\topmargin}{-.375in}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{0.75in}

    %-----------------------------------------------------------
    %Custom commands
    \newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
    \newcommand{\resheading}[1]{{\large \colorbox{mygrey}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}{\textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}\end{minipage}}}}
    \newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{6.5in}
            \textbf{#1} \hfill #2 \\
            \textit{#3} \hfill \textit{#4} 
    \end{minipage}\vspace{-6pt}}

    \newcommand{\ressubsubheading}[2]{
    \begin{tabular*}{6.5in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
            \textit{#1} & \textit{#2} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}
    %-----------------------------------------------------------

    %-----------------------------------------------------------
    %General Resume Tips
    %   No periods!  Technically, nothing in this document is a full sentence.
    %   Use parallelism by ending key words with the same thing,  i.e. "Coordinated; Designed; Communicated".
    %   More tips on bottom of this LaTeX document.
    %-----------------------------------------------------------

    \begin{document}

    \newcommand{\mywebheader}{
    \begin{tabular*}{7in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{{\LARGE DOMARPS}} & \href{mailto:d92@gmail.com}{ste1@gmail.com}\\
        {\href{https}{Portfolio Website}} &  {(+1)1234531432} \\
        \end{tabular*}
    \\
    \vspace{0.1in}}

    % CHANGE HEADER SOURCE HERE
    \mywebheader

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \resheading{Education}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item
                \ressubheading{{UBC}}{expected May 2017 }{{MS in Computer Science}}{}
                    { \footnotesize
                    \begin{itemize}
                        %\resitem{\textbf{Available for internship: July 23, 2009; Graduation follows internship}}
                        \resitem{Coursework : Machine Learning, Artificial Intelligence}
                        \resitem{\textbf{Graduate Teaching Assistant}}
                    \end{itemize}
                    }
            \item
                \ressubheading{PERVSIT}{August 2014}{{Bachelor of Engineering(Hons.) in Electrical and Electronics};\href{https}{GPA:9.64/10.0}}{}
                    { \footnotesize
                    \begin{itemize}
                    \resitem {Coursework : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vitae ultrices. }
                    \resitem {Recipient of the {\bf Best Graduating Student Award} \hfill \href{https}{[Certificate]}}
                    \end{itemize}
                    }

        \end{itemize} % End Education list

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \resheading{Industrial Experience}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 
                \ressubheading{{Intel}}{Bangalore,India}
                    {Logic Design Engineer}{Dec. 2014 -- July 2015}
                    { \footnotesize
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \resitem{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vitae ultrices. }
                        \resitem{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vitae ultrices. }
                    \end{itemize}
                    }
            \item 
                \ressubheading{{Nvidia}}{Bangalore}{Designer}{June 2014 -- Dec. 2014}
                    { \footnotesize
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \resitem{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vitae ultrices. }
                        \resitem{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vitae ultrices. }
                    \end{itemize}
                    }
                \ressubsubheading{Undergraduate Intern,Memory Architecture Team}{Jan. 2014 -- June. 2014}
                    { \footnotesize
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \resitem{Added new features to the performance simulator and validation of the model.}
                        \resitem{Added testslists to verify/validate the model for automation of the various steps involved in validation/verification.}
                        \resitem{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vitae ultrices. }
                    \end{itemize}
                    }
    \end{itemize}  % End Experience list

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \resheading{Research Experience}
    \begin{itemize}
            \item 
                \ressubheading{Parallel Tools for High Speed Machines Circuits}
                {~}
                {\href{http://dummypage}{Computer Lab, University of Ottawa.}} 
                {\textbf{{Summer,2013}}}
              {\footnotesize
              \begin{itemize}
               \resitem{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vitae ultrices. }
               \resitem{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vitae ultrices. }%\hfill [Code] [Results]
              \end{itemize}
              }
    \end{itemize}
    \resheading{\href{dummy}{Projects}}

    \begin{description}
    \item[Pydom:] { \footnotesize Pydom scans through a list of web pages, grabs the HTML source, and parses interactive elements. These interactive elements written to an XML catalog which is used as the main input for a Selenium .Net project.}

    \item[Xerrscrape:] { \footnotesize Used to fill a missing area of product testing, this Python program scans through all XML error logs on the specified server, tallies errors collectively, and sends notifications when an error occurs more than the threshold.}

    \item[.Net CWS Test API:] { \footnotesize This framework provides automated testing for RightNow Connect Web Services for SOAP (.Net Toolkit).  Using reflection, objects and NUnit tests are instantiated based on JSON input.}
    \item[\href{https://bitbucket.org/dhildreth/canon\_webview}{Canon Webcam API}:] {\footnotesize Allows programmatic authentication and control for Canon 360$^\circ$ Webcams in Python.}
    \end{description}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I italicize the "expected Summer 2017" ?